# Ruby - Rails - SQL query - reordering words in a search term

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a project with a search function that is set up as follows:

```
if params[:search_term].present? && params[:search_term].length > 1
  @candidates = @candidates.where("title like ?","%#{params[:search_term]}%")
end
```

The client has asked me to 'loosen up' the search - specifically the word order. At the moment if there is a candidate with a title of `White bar stool` and one searches for `White stool bar`, it returns no results.

Is there any way for me to perform a query where word order is ignored? Or would it be better for me to make new search term params with a different word order, do multiple searches, and combine the results?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: That might help - MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using [`Arel`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel) for this. `Arel` is the underlying query assembler for rails/activerecord (so no new dependencies) and can be very useful when building complex queries because it offers far more depth than the high level `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods`.

`Arel` offers a large selection of predication matchers including in your case `matches_any` and `matches_all`. These methods take an `Array` of `String`s and split them into individual search conditions using `Like`.

For Example to search for all candidates that contain any of the words searched for you can use:

```
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search_for(term)
    candidates = Candidate.arel_table
    where(
       candidates[:title].lower.matches_any(
          term.split.map { |t| "%#{t.downcase}%" }
       )
    )
  end
end
```

The end result of `search_for` (given a search term of 'White stool bar') is:

```
SELECT [candidates].*
FROM [candidates]
WHERE (
  LOWER([candidates].[title]) LIKE '%white%' 
  OR LOWER([candidates].[title]) LIKE '%stool%' 
  OR LOWER([candidates].[title]) LIKE '%bar%')
```

Which appears to be what you are looking for. If it must match all the terms you can instead use `matches_all` which will result in:

```
SELECT [candidates].*
FROM [candidates]
WHERE (
  LOWER([candidates].[title]) LIKE '%white%' 
  AND LOWER([candidates].[title]) LIKE '%stool%' 
  AND LOWER([candidates].[title]) LIKE '%bar%')
```

[See Here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/Predications) for all the available `Arel` predications.

This has added benefits of basic escaping to avoid things like SQL injection.

Comment: I never even knew this bundled with rails - I'm reading through the docs now, many thanks!

Comment: Furthermore this solution actually works and I'll be using a lot more of it in the future, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You can use the MySQL `RLIKE` operator, to match with an specific pattern you can create with your sentence.

```
sentence = 'White stoll bar'
@candidates = @candidates.where('title RLIKE ?', "(#{sentence.tr(' ', '|')})")
```

Comment: This seems tenuous. I do not have MySQL installed or i would test but I assume that if the search condition were to include special caharacters like parens, braces, brackets, forward slashes, etc. that these would need to be escaped appropriately otherwise there would be a query error.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't accept before testing... doesn't seem to return any results :(

Comment: I'd like to know why it doesn't seem to return any result, here there's a [repo](https://bitbucket.org/hnhm/rlike).